# Resize Borderless WinForm with sub controls on border

Tags: c#, winforms, borderless

is there a way I can resize a borderless form with controls that are on the border with one code?

The Problem is I can't resize when I put a close, maximize and minimize button in the top right corner.

[Close, Maximize & Minimize Buttons Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Bp8.png)

I know, it's possible with this code to resize all sub controls. But the problem is I can't use the full space of the Buttons. If I m too near to the border with my cursor it switches to the resizer.

```
private void Controls_Bar_Top_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        subClassChildren(this.Controls);
    }
    const int edge = -32;

    class MouseFilter : NativeWindow
    {
        private Form form;
        public MouseFilter(Form form, Control child)
        {
            this.form = form;
            this.AssignHandle(child.Handle);
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            const int wmNcHitTest = 0x84;
            const int htTransparent = -1;

            if (m.Msg == wmNcHitTest)
            {
                var pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
                if (pos.X < this.form.Left + edge ||
                    pos.Y < this.form.Top + edge ||
                    pos.X > this.form.Right - edge ||
                    pos.Y > this.form.Bottom - edge)
                {
                    m.Result = new IntPtr(htTransparent);
                    return;
                }
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
    private void subClassChildren(Control.ControlCollection ctls)
    {
        foreach (Control ctl in ctls)
        {
            var rc = this.RectangleToClient(this.RectangleToScreen(ctl.DisplayRectangle));
            if (rc.Left < edge || rc.Right > this.ClientSize.Width - edge ||
                rc.Top < edge || rc.Bottom > this.ClientSize.Height - edge)
            {
                new MouseFilter(this.ParentForm, ctl);
            }
            subClassChildren(ctl.Controls);
        }
    }
```

I just want a code where the resize pointer just shows up when I hit the shadow of the control. Right now it shows already up when I am like 5px away from the shadow.

The Code I use for my form to resize is this:

```
 protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE = 10;
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x0084/*NCHITTEST*/ :
                base.WndProc(ref m);

                if ((int)m.Result == 0x01/*HTCLIENT*/)
                {
                    Point screenPoint = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
                    Point clientPoint = this.PointToClient(screenPoint);
                    if (clientPoint.Y <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                    {
                        if (clientPoint.X <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)13/*HTTOPLEFT*/ ;
                        else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)12/*HTTOP*/ ;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)14/*HTTOPRIGHT*/ ;
                    }
                    else if (clientPoint.Y <= (Size.Height - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                    {
                        if (clientPoint.X <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)10/*HTLEFT*/ ;
                        else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)1/*HTCAPTION*/ ;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)11/*HTRIGHT*/ ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (clientPoint.X <= RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE)
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)16/*HTBOTTOMLEFT*/ ;
                        else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE))
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)15/*HTBOTTOM*/ ;
                        else
                            m.Result = (IntPtr)17/*HTBOTTOMRIGHT*/ ;
                    }
                }
                return;

            case WM_NCPAINT:
                if (m_aeroEnabled)
                {
                    var v = 2;
                    DwmSetWindowAttribute(this.Handle, 2, ref v, 4);
                    MARGINS margins = new MARGINS()
                    {
                        bottomHeight = 1,
                        leftWidth = 0,
                        rightWidth = 0,
                        topHeight = 0
                    }; DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this.Handle, ref margins);
                }
                break;
            default: break;

        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
```

Comment: Why not use WinForms built-in layout controls and control anchoring?

Comment: because i want a white "control bar" but on the left side i have an "navigation bar" where i can navigate to different user controls by clicking a button this is docked to the left side so there is no control bar on top and i dont like the black border of the default layout. I just wanted an black shadow. :)

Comment: None of that means you can't use the built-in layout controls.

Comment: You are discovering why a border is useful.  Yes, it provides adequate space for the user to place the mouse cursor when resizing the window.  Not something you can ignore in your own borderless window, the only capability you really added is that the border can look whichever way you want.